# Selecting the correct input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the id's of dynamic input fields in my code. When clicking a button, the form will create a form field like this:

```
<td><input type="text" id="field_a_1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="field_b_1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="field_c_1"></td>
```

When I click on the button again I get this:

```
<td><input type="text" id="field_a_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="field_b_2"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="field_c_2"></td>
```

What I want to do is select only the field id that I need to pull the value from that particular input and pass it to a variable like this:

```
var example = $(":input:eq(0)").val();
```

I know that by adding the `:eq(0)` after the `:input` selector it will only grab the id for `field_a_1`, so how do I set it up so that I can pull just the field that I need to assign it to a variable?

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing... do your inputs change dynamically with a button push? Are you trying to target only the 1st, 2nd, etc input field after each button push?

Comment: Perhaps you could reword the statements just a bit to clarify your desired "pull just the field that I need to assign it to a variable" and "select only the field id that I need to pull the value from that particular input" cause me to wonder a bit.

Comment: fudgy, what I meant to say is that when I click on the button again I get a new set of inputs with new id's. The first set in the example represents a single table row. The second set is actually a new table row and does not alter the first row. So as I click the button I will get a new table row that will increment the number in the id names. What I needed was to be able to calculate the values of each row individually, therefore needing to be able to select the correct id's for each row. You'll have to forgive me since I'm new to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the ID is for. So you can single out a particular element.

```
$('#field_b_2').val();   // Will return the element with that ID.
```

The `#` indicates that you are looking for an element with an ID, as opposed to `.` which would look for an element (or elements) with a class:

```
$('.someClass').val();   // Will return elements with that class
```

Please remember that IDs may not be shared among elements. Only one element may have a particular ID.

Classes, on the other hand, can be shared among as many elements as you need.

Comment: +1 - This is probably what he's looking for with the class, but I can't really tell from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the id of the element you should do:

```
var example = $(":input:eq(0)").attr("id");
```

And then you can access the field again later with:

```
$("#" + example).show();    //or whatever you want to do
```

Comment: You can just do `var example = $(":input").attr("id");` :)

Comment: but he needs to select a specific one with an index. If he needs anything but the first one, your code wouldn't work.

Comment: Since you're not passing a variable into `:eq(0)` that's beside the point :)  But yes, what I posted is just a quicker shortcut for your *specific* posted code.

Answer (score 0):

your Input Ids keep changing like : 
When you click first time it will All: field_a_1 then , field_a_2,  etc.

you simply using this to getting the correct values.

```
$('input[id^=field_]').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```